# Application of Jensen's inequality in a proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

The problem I am on is number 7, I included 6 to show you the relevant result. I have proven number 6.

Number 7, where do I start? what assumptions can I make?

Comment: Hint: log is concave...

Comment: What does "As an application of Jensen's inequality (which choice of $f$?)" mean... in particular the part in the parenthesis is illegible.

Comment: @Macavity can you help me please? I don't know how to get rid of the log once i've used it to show what I need.

Comment: You don't need to get rid of log, as it is strictly increasing, for positive numbers $a \ge b \iff \log a \ge \log b$ so proving the inequality in terms of logs is equivalent to proving the original one. For some reason if you want to get rid of it, take exponentials on both sides.

Comment: @Macavity here's what I get:

take log of the left side, then expand it as a sum as i've done below. i apply jensen's inequality to get that it is $\geq \log(\lambda_1 x_1 + . . . + \lambda_n x_n)$

this is close but I can't put those lambdas back in the exponents, can i?

Comment: You have the wrong sign there - it should be $\le$, though the rest looks fine. Just note that this RHS is the log of your original inequality's RHS and you're done.

Comment: @Macavity thank you! do you think that "specifically, conclude" bit was to show the mmain result, or is that a separate part of the proof?

Comment: I have no idea where you see "specifically, conclude" above. If it's there, it should mean use the main result to show a particular case.

Comment: @Macavity why do people say "concave" to mean "concave down"? I just wrote an entire proof (of more or less garbage now) since I assuemd that was concave down. whatever, I can't even care anymore, the amount of work i've had recently is stupid. i just want to graduate.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** a $\log$ can be a way to change products to sums.

Comment: what base for the logarithm? does it matter?

Comment: okay, now that i've got a bit on this..

 I take log of the left side, $\log(x_1^{\lambda_1} . . .x_n^{\lambda_n}) = \lambda_1 \log(x_1) +  . . . + \lambda_n \log(x_n)$. Log is concave so jensen's applise, but that doesn't give me the result I want does it?

Comment: @terribleatmath take logs of **both sides**, then you get exactly Jensen inequality.

Comment: @Macavity when you take the log of both sides, do you not end up with $\lambda_1 \log x_1 +...+ \lambda_n \log x_n \ge \log (\lambda_1 x_1 +...+ \lambda_n x_n)$ which is the opposite inequality from Jensen and what we set out to prove?

Comment: @user137684 $a\ge b \implies \log a \ge \log b$, so I am not sure why you invert the sign.